# Add select box based on value in other select box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select box on my web page, when i selct a value it should add an other select box and if i select a value on second select box i need to add a third select box
Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js">   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"     
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.js">  
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
 $(function() {
        $('#colorselector').change(function(){
            $('.colors').hide();
           $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
   });
//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="colorselector">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>

</select>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> <select id="colorselector">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
</select>  </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> 
<select id="colorselector">
<option value="one">one</option>
 <option value="two">two</option>
 <option value="three">three</option>
 </select> 
 </div>


<div id="one" class="colors" style="display:none"> one... </div>
<div id="two" class="colors" style="display:none"> 
<select id="colorselector">
<option value="one">four</option>
<option value="two">five</option>
<option value="three">six</option>
</select> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the second select box, but i cant able to add the third one based on the select select box value

Comment: Make that into a fiddle or snippet so we can easily test and help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone has said above, IDs must be unique.

Use:

```
Yellow > two
```

http://jsfiddle.net/psyat5s8/